# How can I create common class for entities

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am getting `org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException` error when I run my application and I have checked http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException but I couldn't figure out the problem

The error that I am getting

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.2:run (default-cli) on project demo: Process terminated with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.2:run (default-cli) on project demo: Process terminated with exit code: 1
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Process terminated with exit code: 1
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.JavaProcessExecutor.run (JavaProcessExecutor.java:74)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo.run (RunMojo.java:68)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:218)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.execute (AbstractRunMojo.java:205)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I have 2 entities. One is student other one is teacher. But class atributes are the some. Thefore, I wanted to create a common class and extend common class with Student and Teacher classes. My classes are as below;

NOTE: For the first step I only made the changes on the `Student.java` class

`Student.java`

```java
package com.example.demo.entity;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinTable;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToMany;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Student")
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Student extends User {

    public Student(String name, String email, LocalDate dob) {
        setName(name);
        setEmail(email);
        setDob(dob);
    }

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "enrolled", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "course_id")
    )
    @Getter @Setter 
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Course> enrolledCourses = new HashSet<>();
}
```

`User.java`

```java
package com.example.demo.entity;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Period;

import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Transient;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.NonNull;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String id;
    @NonNull private String name;
    @NonNull private String email;
    @NonNull private LocalDate dob;
    @Transient @NonNull private Integer age;

    public Integer getAge() {
        return Period.between(this.dob, LocalDate.now()).getYears();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must annotate the `User` class with [`@MappedSuperclass`](https://javadoc.io/doc/jakarta.persistence/jakarta.persistence-api/latest/jakarta.persistence/jakarta/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html)

So you `User` class should be.

```java
package com.example.demo.entity;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Period;

import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.MappedSuperclass;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Transient;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.NonNull;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@MappedSuperclass
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String id;
    @NonNull private String name;
    @NonNull private String email;
    @NonNull private LocalDate dob;
    @Transient @NonNull private Integer age;

    public Integer getAge() {
        return Period.between(this.dob, LocalDate.now()).getYears();
    }
}
```